# Mysql function - cant figure it out

Tags: mysql

i'm using MySql Workbench and im unable to figure out this.

```
      delimiter $$
CREATE function `klientu_copy`() 
 DECLARE v_laiks TIMESTAMP;
 DECLARE v_liet VARCHAR(200);
set v_laiks = now();
set v_liet = current_user;

if (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
insert into kopija_klienti values (v_liet,v_laiks,old.Vards,old.Uzvards,null,null);
ELSEif (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
insert into kopija_klienti values (v_liet,v_laiks,null,null,new.Vards,new.Uzvards);
ELSEif (TG_OP='UPDATE') THEN
insert into kopija_klienti values (v_liet,v_laiks,old.Vards,old.Uzvards,new.Vards,new.Uzvards);
end if;

END; $$

delimiter ;
```

> 21:24:22 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''klientu_copy' ()  BEGIN   DECLARE v_laiks timestamp;  DECLARE v_liet varchar; s' at line 1 0.000 sec

Did try set @variable / declare @variable, cant figure this out. I'm still learning :)

Comment: You are missing a ) on the line `insert into kopija_klienti values (v_liet,v_laiks,old.Vards,old.Uzvards,null,null;`

Comment: Did forget to close ) on your first insert?

Comment: Thanks, didnt even see that... but still got the same problem :)

Comment: Can you use `'` to delimit function names? I usually use `\``, and think `"` is supported with "ANSI SQL" on; but I've never seen single quotes used. Also, as far as I know, `NEW` is only valid in the context of certain triggers; and your function has no return type. You may want to start with the official docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: well i have the exact same code working on postgresql but i can't seem to make it work on workbench.

Comment: The error message you posted would suggest the single quotes are the issue; different sql dialects have different rules like that; for example, I am pretty sure MSSQL would reject the `\``'s commonly used in MySQL. Also, I believe the last `END` needs to use the substituted delimiter, otherwise MySQL won't know the proc declaration is supposed to end there.

Comment: Well ye, did change everything, still the same problem... im guess i'm just blind. Well i'll keep looking and post answer as soon as i " will " find the error. :)

Comment: You changed `'klientu_copy'` to `\`klientu_copy\`` and the error did not change? _Note, that I am saying change the single quote use there to the "tick" (shift `~`)._

Comment: ```Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE v_laiks timestamp;  DECLARE v_liet VARCHAR(200); set v_laiks = now(); se' at line 2```

And yes i did change it to client_copy as you told me `

Comment: @Uueerdo will update how it looks now.

Comment: Refer to my first comment; I know I made edits to it, maybe you didn't see them all (as SO doesn't notify on edits).

Comment: @Uueerdo Thanks, but what in this case i have to return or do i even have to return something.

Comment: In MySQL, functions have to have a return type, and I believe must return; if you don't care about the return value though, you could just `RETURNS INT` and then at the end of the body do `RETURN 0;`

Answer (score -1):

You must specify the length of the `varchar` variable, like `varchar(100)`

Also add the closing `(` for the first insert.

Comment: Yes, but that is not the first and only error in the code.

Comment: Yes, also you didn't add the closing `(` for the first insert, I have edited my answer. Why the down vote though?

Comment: Keep searching. There are more errors in there. I count at least 5 in total

Comment: `end;` should be `end //`?

Comment: I agree with Sarthak Sharma.  Add the // to the end.

Comment: Did add varchar (200) + end // still have the problem. Thanks tho! :)